# How to get High Fidelity audio output with Sennheiser HD 4.40 BlueTooth HeadSet?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, output

My bluetooth headphones(Sennheiser HD 4.40 BT) only provide headset unit audio when connected to this laptop. How do I get High Fidelity audio?

This issue started when the headphones got removed from the list of paired devices. Once I paired them again and connected them, there was no High Fidelity output anymore.

What can I do?